# How to build a table for a dictionary with translations and synonyms

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I do work with databases (php/mySQL) for ages, but after two weeks of thinking and trying, I have to admit that I have no clue how to achieve my goal. Any help or hint is welcome.

What data do I have?

- A list of words in language A and their related synonyms (if any) and the related word in language B and their related synonym (if any). See the (data not a table) example below (word 2/4, word 3/5/6, word C/D are synonyms)

```
    languageA            -->> languageB
    --------------------------------------
    word1                -->> wordA
    word2, word4         -->> wordC, wordD
    word3, word5, word6  -->> wordB
```

Do know that the number of synonym is not limited to any number (in practice roughly 6).

What do I like to achieve:

(with plain queries in mySQL or a combination of some php loops and mySQL queries)

- A list of words in language A with their synonyms (if any) and their related words in language B and their synonyms (if any).
- And the other way around: language B to language A.

```
    languageA              -->> languageB
    --------------------------------------
    word1                -->> wordA
    word2, word4         -->> wordC, wordD
    word3, word5, word6  -->> wordB

    languageB    -->> languageA
    --------------------------------------
    wordA        -->> word1
    wordB        -->> word3, word5, word6
    wordC, wordD -->> word2, word4
    wordD, wordC -->> word2, word4
```

Questions:

- what is the best way store the data in a table (or tables) and to have a minimum of data redundancy?
- with what kind of query (or combination of php and a query) can I output the above listings?

What I've tried:

I have tried several things like two tables: TableA and TableB whereby I joined TableA.LangB with TableB.LangB like so:

```
   TableA                  TableB

   LangA | synA  | LangB   LangB | synB  | LangA
   ---------------------   ---------------------
   word1 |       | wordA   wordA |       | word1
   word2 | word4 | wordC   wordC | wordD | word2
   word4 | word2 | wordC   wordD | wordC | word2
   word3 | word5 | wordB   wordB |       | word3
   word3 | word6 | wordB
```

The last attempt was with one table like below:

```
   languageA  | languageB
   ----------------------
   word1       | wordA
   word2       | wordC
   word2       | wordD
   word4       | wordC
   word4       | wordD
   word3       | wordB
   word5       | wordB 
   word6       | wordB
```

The (almost) achieved goals where accomplished with:

- Q1: SELECT languageA, languagB FROM table GROUP BY languagA,languageB
- Q2: SELECT languageB, languagA FROM table GROUP BY languagB,languageA

In Q1 I get the languageB translation and synonyms for the languageA words, but I lack the synonyms of languageA

In Q2 I get the languageA translation and synonyms for the languageB words, but I lack the synonyms of languageB

Comment: Do you have any idea of how you want to design your DB ? I'd build it with 3 tables, but I'd like to know how **you** would have done it

Comment: As I wrote, I have no clue how to store the data in a smart way. I have updated the question with "what I've tried".

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 entities, `word` and `language`

A `word` can be defined such as

```
id | word
```

A `language` can be defined such as

```
id | language
```

The relation between word and language is such as

- For 1 unique word, there is only 1 language
- For 1 unique language, there can be many words

This is a *One-To-Many* or *Many-To-One* relation

Since `word` holds the lowest relation, the tables `words` and `languages` can be defined such as :

**languages**

```
id | language
```

**words**

```
id | word | id_language
```

Where `id_language` is a foreign key to the table `language`

---

A word can have synonyms, which means that the entity `word` has a relation with itself

When a word has many synonyms, they have in common a *meaning*, that holds eventually a definition, like in a regular dictionary

We can have a new entity `meaning` such as :

```
id | definition
```

The relation between a `word` and a `meaning` can be defined such as :

- For 1 unique meaning, there can be many words (synonyms)
- For 1 unique word, there can be many meanings (homonyms)

This is a *Many-To-Many* relation and the tables are defined such as :

**words** (nothing changed)

```
id | word | id_language
```

**meanings**

```
id | definition
```

**synonyms**

```
id_word | id_meaning
```

Where `id_word` is a foreign key to the table `words` and `id_meaning` to the table `meanings`.

The primary key of this table is the **combination of both foreign key**

---

Because the table `words` holds the relation with the language, the table `synonyms` regroup the words having the same meaning **no matter their language**

The french verb for *to eat* is *manger*. There is a slang synonym, *bouffer*. They all means the same thing *"nom nom nom"*

There is a french verb, *sourire* that means *"When one code is finally working"*. It can be translated in english by *to smile* or *to grin*

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE languages
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE words
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  word VARCHAR(255),
  id_language INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id_language) REFERENCES languages(id)
);

CREATE TABLE meaning
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  definition VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE synonym
(
  id_word INT NOT NULL,
  id_meaning INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id_word) REFERENCES words(id),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id_meaning) REFERENCES meaning(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id_word, id_meaning)
);

INSERT INTO languages (name) VALUES ('French'), ('English');
INSERT INTO words (word, id_language) VALUES ('Manger', 1), ('Bouffer', 1), ('Sourire', 1), ('To eat', 2), ('To smile', 2), ('To grin', 2);
INSERT INTO meaning (definition) VALUES ('Nom nom nom'), ('When one code is finally working');
INSERT INTO synonym (id_word, id_meaning) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (5, 2), (6, 2);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT w.word AS 'Word',
       l.name AS 'Language',
       m.definition AS 'Definition'
FROM words w
INNER JOIN languages l
ON w.id_language = l.id
INNER JOIN synonym s
ON w.id = s.id_word
INNER JOIN meaning m
ON s.id_meaning = m.id
ORDER BY m.definition;
```

**Output**

```
| Word     | Language | Definition                       |
| -------- | -------- | -------------------------------- |
| Manger   | French   | Nom nom nom                      |
| Bouffer  | French   | Nom nom nom                      |
| To eat   | English  | Nom nom nom                      |
| Sourire  | French   | When one code is finally working |
| To smile | English  | When one code is finally working |
| To grin  | English  | When one code is finally working |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jpqb4tYoj9eahqBrLq2o7V/0)

Comment: Impressive, I learned a lot, thanks Cid! (the +1 doesn't work yet with my reputation).